# Web Browser Plugin that Allows user to view Message Traffic

Tags: plugins, internet-explorer

What is the name of the IE plug in that someone can download (I think from Microsoft) that lets a developer (well, anyone who gets the plug-in, actually) to view the message traffic that goes on behind the scenes from the browser to the server?  I saw this one in action but I forget its name.  And I think, for the FireFox broswer, you can simply turn it on somehow without getting a plug in.

It cuts the browser window in half horizonally and the bottom half is also divided vertically and you can see the GET and POST messages as well as the complete header information that is sent to the server from the browser across the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpWatch](http://httpwatch.com/) is a great plugin for IE, but it's not free. Microsoft also released a free tool called [VRTA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=119f3477-dced-41e3-a0e7-d8b5cae893a3&displaylang=en) which works for all browsers, but isn't a plugin.

Comment: Good Answer.
So are the other answers too.
I wonder if I can share credit.

Answer (score 1):

For firefox it's called [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829). Another option of course is [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Good Answer
So are the other answers too.
I wonder if I can share credit.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is from Microsoft.

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Good Answer
So are the other answers too.
I wonder if I can share credit.